# Building Monero From Source on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: monerod, windows, build, git, building

I am following the Windows Guide here to compile from Source:
https://github.com/monero-project/monero

When I enter the command:
  *make release-static-win64*

I get the following error:

```
> spencer@aleph4 MINGW64 /c/Users/Spencer/Monero
> #  make release-static-win64 mkdir -p build/release cd build/release && cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" -D STATIC=ON -D ARCH="x86-64" -D
> BUILD_64=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_TAG="win-x64" -D
> CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../cmake/64-bit-toolchain.cmake -D
> MSYS2_FOLDER=c:/msys64 ../.. && make CMake Error: Error: generator :
> MSYS Makefiles Does not match the generator used previously: NMake
> Makefiles Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles
> directory or choose a different binary directory. make: ***
> [Makefile:111: release-static-win64] Error 1
> 
> spencer@aleph4 MINGW64 /c/Users/Spencer/Monero
> #
```

Comment: really why will D:\Users\...\monero\build\zzzrelease work same?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, rename the directory

```
C:\Users\...\monero\build\release
```

e.g. to

```
C:\Users\...\monero\build\zzzrelease
```